# Auto Batch file Backup not working after changing sql system port

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

im using this code to take auto daily backups of sql, Now we had to change port of sql and backups no longer work, how to specify the port number in string.

```
DECLARE 
@pathName NVARCHAR(512),
@databaseName NVARCHAR(512) 
SET @databaseName = 'DBNAME' 
SET @pathName = 'C:\new\' + 
    Convert(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '_' + 
    Replace((Convert(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 108)),':','-')+ '_.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE @databaseName TO  DISK = @pathName WITH NOFORMAT, 
    NOINIT,  NAME = N'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: why can't you create a sql maintenance plan rather use your script?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: its a sql-server